# Computing the fixed field of an order 2 element of the Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5) / \Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This question is related to the computation suggested here: [Finding the subfields of the cyclotomic field of order $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332838/finding-the-subfields-of-the-cyclotomic-field-of-order-5)

Let $K = \Bbb{Q(\zeta)}/\Bbb{Q}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive 5th root of unity.
We can identify the Galois group with the following 4 automorphisms:

$$
\mathrm{id}: \zeta \mapsto \zeta \\
\tau_2: \zeta \mapsto \zeta^2 \\
\tau_3: \zeta \mapsto \zeta^3 \\
\tau_4: \zeta \mapsto \zeta^4 \\
$$

A quick check shows that the order of $\tau_4$ is 2, so I'd like to compute its fixed field $H$.

Letting $x$ be an arbitrary element of $K$, I've computed its image under $\tau_4$:

$$
x = a + b\zeta + c \zeta^2 + d\zeta^3 + e\zeta^4 \quad \mapsto \quad \tau_4(x) = a + e\zeta + d\zeta^2 + c\zeta^3 + b\zeta^4.
$$

And so if $x=\tau_4(x)$, then $b=e$ and $d=c$, so
$$
x = a + t_1(\zeta + \zeta^4) + t_2(\zeta^2 + \zeta^3)
$$

for some $t_1, t_2 \in \Bbb{Q}$.

It seems like the actual fixed field is $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^4)$, but I'm not sure if I can conclude that from what I've written.

Have I messed up a calculation somewhere? Or is it perhaps the case that $\zeta^2 + \zeta^3 \in \Bbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^4)$?

Comment: We know that $\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4=-1$, so $\zeta^2+\zeta^3\in\mathbb Q(\zeta+\zeta^4)$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! So by the same logic, $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta^2+\zeta^3) \cong \Bbb{Q}(\zeta + \zeta^4)$?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right!

Comment: Observe that $\zeta^4=\zeta^{-1}$, $\zeta^3=\zeta^{-2}$. Then you can also use the fact that  $$(\zeta+\zeta^{-2})^2=\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}+2.$$ Together with boink's comment you can reach the conclusion that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$, but they may not be needed to satisfy your teacher :-)

Comment: Anyway, +1 for showing your work and being on the right track. I suspect the question to be a duplicate though.

Comment: I'd absolutely agree -- this is really just a minor piece of the linked question, but I've never had luck getting clarifications by commenting on old questions.

(Incidentally, that is a great trick!)